# Am i being MITMed?

Tags: http, man-in-the-middle, http-proxy

Lately i was experiencing weird behavour from some big websites.

More specifically, when i normally tried to connect to facebook, i would be greeted with this login page:

[image]

I have placed these with boxes to protect my privacy, as i don't want the language to be revealed. (I am creeped out by the incident i am describing)

However, in recent times, when i tried to connect to fb, i would see these weird login pages:

[image]

[image]

[image]

All those pictures are different, though two of them are almost identical.
What's even weirder is that when i refreshed the webpage, the original and good login page was shown (the first picture).

Other times, after i logged in, i would be given a message that a verification number was sent to my email. After i provided it back, fb would ask me to reset my password.

Other weird behaviour came from amazon. I would google a book, and when i visited the amazon webpage, i would see a huge captcha with nothing else on the screen.

This peaked my curiosity and i performed a traceroute to facebook.
This is the result:

[image]

I have deleted the first nodes for the sake of my privacy, but as you can see by the ones i have highlighted, the address is "dead beee".

I think this is incredibly suspicious so i posted here.
I don't know if i am being MITMed.

Please also note that i am not a criminal, not a goverment worker or anything... So really the idea of being MITMed is farfetched, but i have to find an answer.

Comment: Check the certificate in your web browser.  Is the certificate a valid certificate for Facebook, signed by a reputable CA?

Comment: These `dead:beee` and `dead:bef0` inside the IPv6 addresses are not a problem, I get these too. It's not an uncommon joke if somebody has too much IPv6 addresses (and usually there are enough). Look at the other joke in the final facebook servers IPv6: `..:face:...`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich actually more than just face, face:b00c